# Center element of pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I have a nav bar and below text I am putting a thin line using `:after`.
I want that line in the middle of the `li` tag.

```css
ul {
  background: black;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #5249FF;
}

ul li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">HOME</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">WORLD</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">SPORTS</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

I want white thin line in the center of each `li` tag.
Any help would be great.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to like this

```css
ul {
  background: black;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #5249FF;
}

ul li::after {
  background: #fff;
  bottom: 10px;
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">HOME</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">WORLD</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">SPORTS</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: I want it below text , not beside text.

Answer (score 1):

to `position: absolute;` something relative to it's parent - you need a `position`ed parent.
Let's use `position:relative;` for the `a` elements:

```css
body{background:#444;}

ul {
  background: black;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*padding: 20px 10px;*/
}

ul li a {
  position:relative;  /* add */
  display: block;     /* add */
  padding: 20px 10px; /* add */
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul li a:hover {       /* anchor hover! */
  background: #5249FF;
}

ul li a:after {       /* anchor after! */
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 20%; 20% of what*/
  top: 40px;
  /*left: 15px; 15px is not centering*/
  left: 0; 
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto /* center */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">HOME</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">WORLD</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">SPORTS</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Don't use paddings on LI elements - think about accessibility, rather set your paddings to the Anchor elements, that way their clickable size is expanded.

Answer (score 0):

`position:absolute` elements are "absolute" relatively to the first `position:relative` parent, at your example, there is no `relative parent`, therefore they become relative to `body`.

What you need to do is to add `position:relative` to your `li` element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `left: 50%; transform:translateX(-50%);` inside `ul li:after` and `position:relative;` inside `ul li`

```css
ul {
  background: black;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:relative;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #5249FF;
}

ul li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">HOME</a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#">WORLD</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">SPORTS</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```